# How do I change color of the class properties in Sublime text 2?

Tags: php, syntax-highlighting, sublimetext, sublimetext2

Currently this is the code that highlights all variables, including class properties (they are red):

```
    <dict>
        <key>name</key>
        <string>Variables</string>
        <key>scope</key>
        <string>variable, support.variable</string>
        <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string></string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#dc322f</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

How can I change the color of class properties only?

`$object->property = 'xxx';`

so `$object` should still be red, but I want `property` in a different color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`variable.other.property` should do the trick:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Variables</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>variable.other.property</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>fontStyle</key>
        <string></string>
        <key>foreground</key>
        <string>#00ff00</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: @Alex: can you provide an example of what other types of keywords are changed as well?

Comment: well it also highlights variables like `$this->$something`. $something should be highlighted like normal variable, because that's what it is

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<string>variable, support.variable</string>
```

To:

```
<string>variable.other.property</string>
```